# How to check if price is going up in 10 consecutive trades in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have intra-day price data for stock trades and need to write a code to determine the instances in which the following condition is met: Price should go up at least for 10 consecutive trades.

Here is a sample of my data (time is number of minutes in the day, if it's 1 am my time will be 60, if it's 2 am, my time will be 120 etc.):

```
       Obs    Time    Symbol            Price      
       1       288    AA                36.2800     
       2       304    AA                36.2800     
       3       305    AA                36.3400     
       4       307    AA                36.2800     
       5       311    AA                36.1500     
       6       337    AA                36.2000
```

How can I write this code? Probably a loop is necessary but I can not figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write these iterative statements in SAS? I am trying to identify the intervals during the day where the stock price kept going up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128965/how-to-write-these-iterative-statements-in-sas-i-am-trying-to-identify-the-inte)

Comment: Do not post multiple questions on the same topic.

Comment: Sorry. This was just one component of the other question that has three components. I was just hoping to have a starting point so I could have a better approach to the more complicated question in the other question. I'll edit the other one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no missing values, something like:

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  lagPrice=lag(Price) ;
  if Price>lagPrice and not missing(lagPrice) then Increasing ++ 1 ;
  else Increasing=0 ;

  if Increasing > 10 then Trend=1 ;
run ;
```

That will flag the 10th record of an increasing trend, and all those after.  Is that what you want?  Or are you looking for a ways to flag all records involved in the trend?  Or something else??

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. I was trying to identify up and down trends, and find a return based on the 1st and the 10th trades so 10th record is fine.